# OuterGlow effect in WPF not working with layered window?

Tags: c#, wpf, effects

can any one tell me why /no/ outerglow effects are working on my WPF Window? here is an example of the code:

```
<Window x:Class="SocialShock_WPF_Client.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        WindowStyle='None' 
        Background="Transparent" 
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Margin="12" Name="rectangle1" Fill="#FFB75050">
            <Rectangle.BitmapEffect>
                <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Black" GlowSize="20" />
            </Rectangle.BitmapEffect>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the resulting image:

http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/6213/1c1761f31ce6408d948e266.png

No glow around the edge. 
not only is the glow not appearing on the rectangle, but any other controls i add to the window cannot accept glows either.

***EDIT:*** its in .Net 4.0

Comment: Which version of .NET framework are you using? BitmapEffects are deprecated since .NET 4.0

Comment: BitmapEffects do not work in .net 4? how would i do this in .net 4 then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

BitmapEffects are no longer supported in .NET 4.0.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743435.aspx)

> Important  In the .NET Framework 4 or
>   later, the BitmapEffect class is
>   obsolete. If you try to use the
>   BitmapEffect class, you will get an
>   obsolete exception. The non-obsolete
>   alternative to the BitmapEffect class
>   is the Effect class. In most
>   situations, the Effect class is
>   significantly faster.

There isn't a really good substitute but you can try to use a `DropShadowEffect` with a `ShadowDepth` of 0. Example

```
<Rectangle Margin="12" Name="rectangle1" Fill="#FFB75050">
    <Rectangle.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                          Color="Black"
                          Opacity="1"
                          BlurRadius="12"/>
    </Rectangle.Effect>
</Rectangle>
```

If I understood you comment correctly,

**Adding the effect in code behind**

```
DropShadowEffect dropShadowEffect = new DropShadowEffect();
dropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth = 0;
dropShadowEffect.Color = Colors.Black;
dropShadowEffect.Opacity = 1;
dropShadowEffect.BlurRadius = 12;
rectangle1.Effect = dropShadowEffect;
```

**Modifying the effect in code behind**

```
DropShadowEffect dropShadowEffect = rectangle1.Effect as DropShadowEffect;
dropShadowEffect.BlurRadius = 24;
```

Comment: can i see what you were going to post anyways?

Comment: @Tommy: Sure, I didn't save it but I can re-create it

Comment: is there any way to make the rectangle transparent without reducing the visibility of the effect?

Comment: @Tommy: You can change the alpha value of `Fill` for the `Rectangle`, like `<Rectangle Fill="#66B75050">`

Comment: I did try that - it seemed to effect the .Effect property aswell for some reason - will test some more.

Comment: yes, the alpha property on the fill definitely does change the alpha of the effect as well.

Comment: @Tommy: You're right, it does. I tried to wrap the `Rectangle` in a `Border` but the problem was the same.

Comment: @Tommy: Giving that problem some more thought, and the reason for it is pretty clear. When setting opacity or fill alpha value for the `Rectangle` to a lower value, e.g. 0.0, the effect will create a drop shadow for something that isn't there, hence no drop shadow effect. I don't think there's any way around this. You'll have to configure the values depending on each other. Unfortunately, the drop shadow opacity can never go above the Rectangle opacity though